# Change colors boxplots by groups ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this boxplots in shiny and I would like to change colors with vector "cols", change the order of the legend and rename x axis. Do you know the best way to do that? I have tried with scale_fill_discrete and scale_x_discrete and it didn't work.
Thanks!

```
dados7 <- reactive({ 
  dataset1() %>% filter(variable==input$frame) %>% 
    rename( var8 = regiao, var9 = imp, var10 = metodo)
})
```

```
cols<-c("green","orange", "red", "blue","pink","salmon","black")
renderPlotly({
title3<-paste(input$frame, "por região")
if (input$frame=="Taxa_Natalidade")
  
  r<- dados7() %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = var10, y = var9)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = var10), position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
    facet_wrap(vars(var8)) 
  r
})
```

[image]

Comment: if you mutate your x variable so it is a factor, you can specify the order of the levels

Answer (score 1):

Your question is actually a few parts in one.  You are looking to:

1. Change the colors for fill to a specific palette.
2. Change the order of the legend
3. Rename the x axis.

The easy one is #3.  All you have to do is rename the x axis by specifying in `labs(x="new name for your axis")`.  If you are changing the x axis scale with a `scale_x_*` function, you'll want to rename within that function, since `labs()` is just a convenience function for various `scale_*_(name=...)` functions.

Now, for the other questions, it's not possible to provide a good answer without a good dataset, so I'm going to make up some data using the `iris` dataset.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- iris
df$rand_label <- sample(paste0('Type',1:3), nrow(df), replace=TRUE)
```

Now, see a resulting boxplot to be used to demonstrate:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length, fill=rand_label)) +
  geom_boxplot() + theme_classic()
p
```

[image]

### Changing Colors

To change fill colors, you only need to specify via `scale_fill_manual()` by passing the list of colors to the `values=` argument.  Caution: you must supply a list of colors that matches the number of levels in the factor used to define fill.  In this example, `df$rand_label` contains 3 levels, so we need to supply a vector of 3 colors:

```
cols <- c('orange','pink','gray20')
p + scale_fill_manual(values=cols)
```

[image]

If you want to specify to which level the colors are assigned, instead of passing a character vector you can pass either a named vector or a list of `"label name" = "color name"`.  Note that order doesn't matter here, since everything is explicitly defined:

```
cols1 <- c('Type3'='orange','Type2'='pink','Type1'='gray20')
p + scale_fill_manual(values=cols1)
```

[image]

### Changing Ordering

You can change the order of the fill legend in two different ways: (1) change the order of the legend and the positioning on the plot, and (2) just change the order of the items in the legend itself.  First, I'll show you the #1 case (changing order of legend and positioning on the plot).

#### Change order of legend and order on plot

Changing both is more typically what you will do, since we often like the order things appear in the legend to match the order in which they appear on the plot.  The best way to do this is to refactor the column in question and pass an ordered vector to `levels=` matching the order you want.  You then need to call `ggplot()` again with your re-leveled factor:

```
df$rand_label <- factor(df$rand_label, levels=c('Type3','Type1','Type2'))

ggplot(df, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length, fill=rand_label)) +
  geom_boxplot() + theme_classic() + scale_fill_manual(values=cols)
```

[image]

Note that the *order of the colors* is still applied the same, but the *order of the items* is different in the plot.  The order in which the items appear in the legend is also different.

#### Change only order in the legend

If you want to adjust the order of items as they appear in the legend, you can use the `breaks=` argument within `scale_fill_manual()` to define the order in which the items appear.  In this case, we can use this to return the levels to their original order in the plot above, but retain the mixed up ordering we defined by releveling the factor.  Also note that since we're just passing `cols` and not the named vector `cols1`, the colors are applied according to how the levels appear in the legend (not the way in which they are ordered in the factor):

```
df$rand_label <- factor(df$rand_label, levels=c('Type3','Type1','Type2'))

ggplot(df, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length, fill=rand_label)) +
  geom_boxplot() + theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cols, breaks=c('Type1','Type2','Type3'))
```

[image]

You can also use a similar strategy to reorder the x axis: in this case, you would refactor `df$Species` and set the `levels=` according to your preferred order.

Comment: Thanks! It was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried: scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue","green", etc...)
Should work